# how to remove the Patch from console

Tags: patch, windows-installer

I am applying Patch to my programm with command line:

```
msiexec /p Patch.msp -l*v log.txt
```

But how to remove the Patch from console? Not to remove the product at all.Only Patch.
Now I am using ARP Panel for this cause. But i can't get logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No all patches can be removed individually. You must author a special kind of patch called "Uninstallable Patch" in order to remove it.

You can read more here on how to remove patches:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371212(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Starting with Windows Installer 3.0, you can uninstall patches. There are two methods you can use on the command line:

- [**Using MSIPATCHREMOVE on a command line**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372104.aspx#uninstalling_a_patch_using_msipatchremove_on_a__command_line)

```
msiexec /i {GUID-OF-PRODUCT} MSIPATCHREMOVE={GUID_OF_PATCH} /qb
```

- [**Using the standard command line options**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372104.aspx#uninstalling_a_patch_using_the_standard_command_line_options)

```
Msiexec /package {GUID-OF-PRODUCT} /uninstall {GUID_OF_PATCH} /passive
```

For more information, read [Uninstalling Patches](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372104.aspx) article on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers need product's GUID, it's not easy to get it.
Here's another way:

```
Msiexec /i {installpath_of_product} MSIPATCHREMOVE={installpath_of_patch} /qb
```